# How can a torus be turned to a cylinder if the circumference of the outer ring is larger?

Tags: geometry, geometric-topology

I’m not a math professional by any means, I’m just interested in math and this topic has been on my mind for a while, and I just couldn’t find an answer. Also, on the same vein, how can you make a cylinder out of a piece of paper? The inner circle would have a smaller circumference than the outer, but each side of the paper has the same length.

Comment: You should perhaps elaborate on what you're referring to by these constructions because I've  honestly no clue what you mean. Why would these circumferences be larger/smaller? Unless you're using crude constructions IRL with actual paper, it may be worthwhile to keep in mind that these constructions are more based on the ideal/theoretical way of doing this.

Comment: Well, wouldn’t the inner circle of a torus theoretically be smaller than the outer circle? I’ve seen a video online of a torus being broken and turned a cylinder (it was a 3D demonstration). So that’s where the torus question comes from.

Comment: What inner circle? The only one that I can think you're referring to is the "doughnut hole," so to speak. If you mean inside the torus itself ("inside the donut"), then tori are defined as surfaces, so it'd be more like if the entire torus was made from an infinitely-thin sheet of paper. (i.e. no thickness or inner radius in that respect)

Comment: Well, what I mean is: if you take a piece of paper and turn it into a cylinder and then glue the two hole of a cylinder, you have a torus, right? If you were to take a pice of paper, and slice the torus right in the middle, that cross section, you would see two circles: the outer ring of the torus, it’s circumference, and the inner ring, the “doughnut hole.” These two rings have different lengths. But if you were to straighten the torus back into a cylinder, those two rings would return back to straight lines of equal length. I’m confused about that.

Answer (score 3):

The math of topology is an abstraction that has no *direct* connection to manipulating physical objects. But in this case, we can tie things to physical intuition pretty well.

When we talk about turning a cylinder into a torus by gluing together the ends, there's two ways we can mean it:

- We can imagine it abstractly, where the ends of the cylinder are just declared to be the same. This is similar to video game behavior in games such as Pac-Man, where objects going off one side of the screen return on the other side as though those points were adjacent.
- We can perform a continuous deformation of the cylinder inside $\mathbb R^3$ until the ends are actually in the same location and we get a torus. Here, continuity is what matters, which means that points that start out close together stay close together (and there's a precise $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of this). The physical intuition is that you have an infinitely flexible and stretchable material that won't break: more like rubber than like paper.

A cylinder made out of paper should be thought of mathematically as a metric space, not a topological space, because paper can't be stretched: if you imagine an ant following a path on the surface of the paper, the length of the path won't change for the ant when you bend the paper. In this respect, a cylinder *can't* be turned into a torus - mathematically or physically.

We can actually prove this mathematically in terms of [Gaussian curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_curvature), which, informally, measures how much the way the surface bends affects distance. A cylinder has zero Gaussian curvature everywhere - it is actually no different in terms of small-scale distances from a flat piece of paper (and we can make a cylinder out of a sheet of paper by bending it). A torus has positive Gaussian curvature on the outside and negative on the inside. Gauss's [theorema egregium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theorema_Egregium) says, therefore, that we can't turn the cylinder into anything like the torus by "local isometry", which translates almost exactly into our intuition of what's physically possible with a sheet of paper.

Comment: So if I’m understanding well, my first question was just a misconception on my part then? I was trying to think of an abstract context represented visually into a direct physical way. Also, if I were to take a cylinder out of paper and walk around the circumference of the inside and of the outside, would they be the same lengths?

Comment: Yes, and (up to the thickness of the paper, which we assume is 0 in the mathematical world) yes.